# "Work off" vs. "work off of"

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I heard an American colleague say "This is a template you can work off of". The two prepositions sounded a bit odd to me one after the other, but I don't know if that is standard or "formal" English. I am learning British English, so I'd also like to know how a British person would express the same idea. Thanks.

Comment: I can't speak to how a British speaker may say this, but it is common to say this is the US. it is not "formal," however, it's a casual saying that is only preferred in conversation. The more formal written version would be "This is a template off which you can work." This sentence sounds odd to say or read so it is not often used. A better way to say this would be "template you can work **from**." This version is also not "formal" it's mainly used for conversation. The best, formal way would be to say: "This is a template you can use as a basis for your work." I assume BrE uses this too, idk.

Comment: This British speaker regards 'off of' as nonstandard, mainly Southern English - as in the Rolling Stones' _Hey, hey, you, you, get off of my cloud_.

Comment: 'off of' is to be found in Samuel Pepy's diary written in the 1660s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more subtle than it might seem.

To **work off** is basically the same in British and American English (see the Collins Dictionary) when it means to work off a debt or weight, for example. And also when it means the basis of something. See the two BrE examples below.

- We are working off our debt by working extra hours everyday.
- We are working off weight by exercising a lot.

Here is a UK blogger who uses "work off of":

> I’ve had to learn to work from home which has been so difficult as I’m
> constantly thinking about what needs to be done around the house; I
> don’t have an office that I can shut myself away in and I have **to work
> off of my dining room table**. [work off of my dining table](https://www.newgrad.co.uk/newgradblog/balancingfulltimeworkeducation)

Here is another:

> Considering the imagery I wanted to use depicting things which are
> dear to me or resonate with myself I began sketching possible ideas to
> then work off of. [work off of](https://journal.falmouth.ac.uk/oliviawinter2/2020/05/05/double-exposure/)

To work off of [some thing] means: **to use that thing as a basis to do something else**. Here is a [list of sentences](https://ludwig.guru/s/I+work+off+of) from Ludwig.guru

As Kate Bunting says, one can use "work from", too: to work from a template or work off of a template or to work off a template [declarative only].

Here's the tricky part: In order to create a question (interrogative form) using this "of" form, you need the "of" because without it, the meaning reverts to the other use without it.

- How much debt **did you work off**?
- *What template did you work off*? [BUZZER}

Correct question: **What template did you work off of**?

Please note: The reason one says "work off of" comes from an older usage in the language: I work off of a table. I work off of a flat piece of wood.

Answer (score 2):

"Off of" is colloquial/informal English. It's non-standard in both US and British English.

It is also used in the UK in some dialects/regions. It's not just an American thing. For example, I'm Scottish and we use it too. It doesn't sound odd to me at all.

You must also remember there are lots of accents and dialects in the UK, so to ask how British people would say something is very difficult to answer, since it depends on where you come from in the UK.  The same goes for the US. There isn't just one American accent - there are regional variations there too.

If you want something a bit more standard use "a template you can work from" in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Collins Dictionary [says](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/off):

> The phrasal preposition **off of** is old in English, going back to the 16th century. Although usage guides reject it as redundant, recommending *off* without *of*, the phrase is widespread in speech, including that of educated speakers: *Let's watch as the presidential candidates come off of the rostrum and down into the audience*. *off of* is rare in edited writing except to give the flavor of speech